# JavaFx combobox from mysql

Tags: mysql, javafx, combobox

Good Day I am completely new to coding. I am building an app which uses a combobox besides other library items. The problem I am facing is that while attempting to populate combobox items from a Mysql Db the item values get duplicated each time the drop down is clicked.

How I can keep this from happening ? I do understand that my approach itself could be erroneous.

```
    @FXML
public void getStation() {
    String sqlStationName = " select * from station ";

    try {
        conn = (Connection) DBConnection.connect();
        PreparedStatement pstStn = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStationName);
        ResultSet stnRS = pstStn.executeQuery(sqlStationName);

        while (stnRS.next()) {

        comboBoxStation.getItems().add(stnRS.getString("stationName"));


        }

        stnRS.close();
        pstStn.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERR" + ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps you could try clearing the items, before adding more. I'm unsure however if you really want to query on every click, it seems to be a slight overkill imo.

Comment: How do you use the `getStation` method? `@FXML` (even though it's unnecessary for public methods) seems could indicate that you use it as event handler from the fxml file. Please add information on how this method is used to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.@el_chupacabra your observation is right , I don't really want to query on every click , I just want the items to be displayed if the user clicks on the combobox button and then reset or cleared when the list is closed.  Fabian yes the @FXML usage is a newbie mistake , the method is called on mouse click .

Comment: When I have to populate a ComboBox, I use this `comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(myList));` where `myList` is an ArrayList of items. Maybe this can help ?

Comment: Yes thanks Jack that's exactly what I tried

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I moved the function to the initialize() method in the controller and created an Observabale list called station

```
     private ObservableList<String> stationsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // 
    String sqlStationName = " select * from station ";

    try {
        conn = (Connection) DBConnection.connect();
        PreparedStatement pstStn = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStationName);
        ResultSet stnRS = pstStn.executeQuery(sqlStationName);

        while (stnRS.next()) {

            stationsList.add(stnRS.getString("stationName"));

        }

        stnRS.close();
        pstStn.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERR" + ex);
    }

}
```

and then left only this line in the original function....seems to be working.

```
    @FXML
private void getStation() {

    comboBoxStation.setItems(stationsList);
}
```